Writer girl on a lonely island
There is this girl who goes to an island to be alone and write, as she is a writer, but from the beginning there seems to be ghost like creature with her all the time, that she doesn't know of. 
The island is isolated and for weekly supplies a man visits with his assistant on a boat, then her boyfriend comes with him to the island to give her a surprise and initially she was okay with him visiting but then she gets upset by the fact that he's disturbing her. 
In-between there is man shown to be whispering in her ear (who's by the way not the ghost) and the ghost seems confused too, the man who whispers, talks the ghost into killing the girl's boyfriend. 
While the ghost seems to be in love with the girl the boyfriend attempts to propose to the girl but she refuses (because of the constant whispering of the whispering man she becomes irritated).
Eventually it's shown that the girl's parents (or her grandparents I am not quite sure) were divorced because of the fights on this very island, it seems because of the "Whisperer". With the turn of events the boyfriend is injured by the ghost and the ghost hides him in the basement. The girl starts regretting what she has done and tries to find him and when she does another angel like person appears and it seems if there is "Whisperer" in her life than an angel is too with her.
They escape with the man who used to visit that island with a boat at the end but the it is revealed in the end that the assistant is also a "Whisperer" who whispers in the ears of the boat man and the movie ends.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Sounds like the 2010 movie The Presence.
The boyfriend showing up, getting a boat to the isolated area and whispering all match your question.

A woman travels to an isolated cabin where she finds herself stalked by an apparition who has come to inhabit her space as his own. With the unexpected arrival of the woman's boyfriend, the dark spirit's haunting grows more obsessive. Soon the woman begins to exhibit weirdly irrational behavior as the thin line between sanity and possession begins to unravel.

Here is the trailer:



